Bamboo build - Error during compilation - package sun.security.mscapi does not exist
I'm trying to configure a Bamboo build for a legacy java application. The build fails to compile with the error 'package sun.security.mscapi does not exist'. The build uses Azul Zulu 1.8.0_422 JDK for compilation. I've looked at similar questions here and all point to including the argument '-XDignore.symbol.file' in the build.
But it didn't work. Interestingly, using Oracle or Azul Zulu JDK on my local machine has no issues compiling the same code.
I don't understand how come local build succeeds without the argument, but the bamboo build fails even with the argument? What could be the difference? How to look for it?
I know, 'sun' packages are not to be used. This is a legacy app that will become obsolete in near future. For now, I just need to get the bamboo build running.
Tried providing the argument '-XDignore.symbol.file' in the build configuration but it didn't work. Local build without this argument works.
